# Custom Permission Evaluator is not getting invoked : Spring security 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement custom permission evaluator in my project. I have configured `spring security 3.2 and spring 4`. However, I am not able to get it working.

springframework.version : 4.0.2.RELEASE

springsecurity.version : 3.2.1.RELEASE

I have annotated all my controller methods with `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission()")` annotation. But the call is not going into `hasPermission()` method in my custom evaluator.

My code is pasted below :

**spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled">
        <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
    </global-method-security>

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/auth/auth/denied" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth/auth/login" access="denyAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth/main/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>   
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

    <!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
    <!--<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.cj.customAuthProvider"/>-->

    <beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.mycompany.common.evaluators.AuthorizationEvaluatorController"/>
</beans:beans>
```

**rest-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.reactore.common.web.controller"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain;charset=UTF-8"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:domain-config.xml /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter> 
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/auth/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Permission Evaluator**

```
public class AuthorizationEvaluatorController extends ModuleController implements PermissionEvaluator{

    private boolean checkPermission(Long userId, String permissionId){
        //get user details and check if access is there.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object userId, Object permissionId) {
        System.out.println("Checking the permission......");
        return checkPermission((Long)userId, (String)permissionId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable serializable, String s, Object o) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class RoleController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/role/{roleId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    **@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#roleId,3)")**
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getRoleFromId(@PathVariable("roleId") Long roleId) throws Exception {
        return getRoleService(roleId);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I added the same global-annotation config to the spring context xml. After that, for all the requests it is returning 404, however, the request is not going to the evaluator class.

Comment: I am having similar issue with Spring 4.0.4.RELEASE and Spring Security 3.2.3.RELEASE. Any luck so far?

Comment: Yes, finally I made it to work. The fix for me is given in the answer. Try that out and let me know.

Comment: Good then. I tried your solution, did not work for me though. btw, mine was actually working. just my little carelessness with acl tables naming and annotation placements. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the issue got resolved for me. 
I added the line `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true" />` to my config file and now the evaluator is getting invoked.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was the permission evaluator was invoking with some incorrect parameters. I tried adding this line and it is working now. Can you explain what this particular line of code does and how it is solving the problem?

Comment: where exactly is it placed?